# In the KendoUI framework, is there a global way to turn off animations?

Tags: animation, kendo-ui

Is there a global way to turn off animations on all controls in KendoUI.  I want to have an option to do this so if someone is using a low powered device we can have an option for them to run without animations/transitions.

Something like kendo.enableAnimations(false);

Regards,

Scott

Comment: [Looks like there's way to do this...](http://www.telerik.com/forums/global-disable-animations)

Comment: Thanks for the response mate... but my JS is minified and concatenated so difficult to leave that out...

Comment: Yep, realized it's not really a solution so I only posted as a comment, I'll come back to your question if I find any answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is one undocumented way - `kendo.effects.enable()` and `kendo.effects.disable()`. It is currently used in [the tests](https://github.com/telerik/kendo-ui-core/tree/master/tests) to avoid async assertions.

Comment: Thanks for following this up mate.  Much appreciated.